# How to find efficiently two numbers in an array of which the sum is equal to a specified number?

Tags: algorithm

I thought a way to solve the problem which has the following code:

```
package samueg.algorithm;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[] { -1, 3, 7, 2, 4, 5, -8, 9 };
        int sum = 14;
        int targetIndex1 = -1, targetIndex2 = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {

//          for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
//              if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == sum) {
//                  targetIndex1 = i;
//                  targetIndex2 = j;
//                  break;
//              }
//          }

            for (int j = (i + 1); j < numbers.length; ++j) {
                if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == sum) {
                    targetIndex1 = i;
                    targetIndex2 = j;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (targetIndex1 != -1 && targetIndex2 != -1) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%1$d + %2$d = %3$d",
                        numbers[targetIndex1], numbers[targetIndex2], sum));
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("No targets which satisfy the condition are found.");

    }

}
```

The commented code is not necessary because the judgements they do are already done for index i.
I want to know whether this algorithm is efficient or not and if it's not can someone show me a better one? Thanks.

Comment: The complexity is O (n^2). Can be done ib O (nlogn) by first sorting the array and then iterating in forward and backward direction simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

**Using a hash table:**

For each number `n`:

- Check if `target number - n` is in the hash table. If it is, we've found two numbers summing to the target number.
- Insert `n` into the hash table.

Complexity: Expected `O(n)` (your approach is `O(n2)` because of the double for loop).

Comment: This is certainly a good choice if you have a large set of numbers.  Caution is warranted if you are doing lots of small arrays (constant factors are probably higher for setting up and managing the amortized hash table internals)

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array, set two pointers and move them separately. This should give you a O(n log(n)) solution. I'm not good in java so let me python:

```
def find_indexes(A, s):
    A = sorted(A)
    p1 = 0
    p2 = len(A) - 1
    while not A[p1] + A[p2] == s and p1 < len(A) and p2 >= 0:
        if A[p1] + A[p2] < s:
            p1 = p1 + 1
        if A[p1] + A[p2] > s:
            p2 = p2 - 1
    if A[p1] + A[p2] == s:
        return (p1,p2)
    return None
```